# Array not being returned as expected

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on implementing a Naive Bayes Classification algorithm. I have a method `def prob_continous_value` which is supposed to return the probability density function for an attribute given a class attribute. The problem requires classifying the following datasets:

```
Venue,color,Model,Category,Location,weight,Veriety,Material,Volume
1,6,4,4,4,1,1,1,6
2,5,4,4,4,2,6,1,1
1,6,2,1,4,1,4,2,4
1,6,2,1,4,1,2,1,2
2,6,5,5,5,2,2,1,2
1,5,4,4,4,1,6,2,2
1,3,3,3,3,1,6,2,2
1,5,2,1,1,1,2,1,2
1,4,4,4,1,1,5,3,6
1,4,4,4,4,1,6,4,6
2,5,4,4,4,2,4,4,1
2,4,3,3,3,2,1,1,1
```

```
Venue,color,Model,Category,Location,weight,Veriety,Material,Volume
2,6,4,4,4,2,2,1,1
1,2,4,4,4,1,6,2,6
1,5,4,4,4,1,2,1,6
2,4,4,4,4,2,6,1,4
1,4,4,4,4,1,2,2,2
2,4,3,3,3,2,1,1,1
1,5,2,1,4,1,6,2,6
1,2,3,3,3,1,2,1,6
2,6,4,4,4,2,3,1,1
1,4,4,4,4,1,2,1,6
1,5,4,4,4,1,2,1,4
1,4,5,5,5,1,6,2,4
2,5,4,4,4,2,3,1,1
```

The code for this is written like so:

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import count, index
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from numpy import linalg as LA
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

test_set_Bayes = pd.read_csv("Assignment 2--Training set for Bayes.csv")
training_set_Bayes = pd.read_csv("Assignment 2--Test set for Bayes.csv")

def prob_continous_value(A, classAttribute, dataset, x):
    # calcuate the average for all values of A in dataset with class = x
    a = dataset[dataset[classAttribute] == x][A].mean()
    # calculate the standard deviation for all values A in dataset with class = x
    stdev = dataset[dataset[classAttribute] == x][A].std()
    v = dataset[A].iloc[0]
    print(f"a:{a}, stdev:{stdev}, v:{v}")
    p = (1/(math.sqrt(2*math.pi)*stdev))*math.exp(-((v-a)*(v-a))/(2*stdev*stdev))
    return p

def valueIsNotContinuous(A,dataset):
    # check if value is continuous or not
    x = dataset[A].iloc[0]
    return type(x) == int or type(x) == float


def BayesClassifier(training_set,test_set):
    classAttribute = 'Volume'
    for x in training_set[classAttribute].unique():
        D = len(training_set[classAttribute].index)
        d = len(training_set[training_set[classAttribute] == x].index)
        px = d/D
        print(f'Step 1 calculate p({classAttribute}={x}|x)={px}')
        print(f'p({classAttribute}={x}|x)={px}')
        p = 0
        probabilitiesProduct = 0
        products = [] 
        for A, values in training_set.iteritems():
            if not A == classAttribute:
                print(f'Step 2 calculate p(Ai={A}={classAttribute}|{x})')
                p = prob_continous_value(A, classAttribute, training_set, x)
                print(f'p({A}|{x}) = {p}')
                probabilitiesProduct *= p
                print(f"p(Ai={A}|{classAttribute}={x})={px*probabilitiesProduct}")
        products.append(probabilitiesProduct)
    print(products)



# prompt user to select either ID3 or Bayes classifier.
selection = "Bayes" #= input("Please enter your selection for either ID3 or Bayes classification: ")


if(selection == "Bayes"):
    BayesClassifier(training_set_Bayes,test_set_Bayes)
```

Expected:

Array of probabilities

Actual:

```
[nan]
```

The stdev

```
Technically the stdev is 0 for cases like:

p(Ai=Model|Volume=5)=0.0
Step 2 calculate p(Ai=Category=Volume|5)
38    3
40    3
41    3
Name: Category, dtype: int64
average :3.0, stdev:0.0, value :4
```

I'm unexpectedly getting an error `nan` this should be an array. I'd like to figure out how to return the max from the array.

Comment: Add `print(probabilitiesProduct)` before and after the line `probabilitiesProduct *= p`. What does it output?

Comment: This probably won't solve the entire question, but a product of probabilities should be initialized as 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and it looks like your issue is this line:

`p = (1/(math.sqrt(2*math.pi)*stdev))*math.exp(-((v-a)*(v-a))/(2*stdev*stdev))`

The print statement above it says `stdev` is `0`, so you get a `1/0` error.  In my interpreter it threw a `ZeroDivisionError` at that line, I'm surprised yours didn't.

Setting `stdev = 1` before the division appears to solve the issue, so you need to either use input data that has a non-zero standard deviation, or there's an error in your equation.

Comment: Technically the stdev is 0 for cases like:

p(Ai=Model|Volume=5)=0.0
Step 2 calculate p(Ai=Category=Volume|5)
38    3
40    3
41    3
Name: Category, dtype: int64
average :3.0, stdev:0.0, value :4
```

Comment: But the stdev being 0 is the cause of your problem.  You're getting `nan` because you have division by 0.  What is the expected behaviour when stdev=0?